# How to refresh preferredStatusBarStyle in one ViewController for two or more times

Tags: xcode, colors, ios9, statusbar

My old code :

```
- (void)setStatusBarLight:(BOOL)value {
    if (value) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
    }
}
```

Now setStatusBarStyle is deprecated. Apple says, that i should use **preferredStatusBarStyle**. But this calls only once. But in my option status bar must change color after some user actions in this view controller.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

And **View controller-based status bar appearance** set to **YES** in Info.plist

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for having a view controller with a dark navBar and white statusBar text and present a view controller with a light navBar and black statusBar text:

vc1 (dark navBar, white statusBar text)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
}
```

vc2 (light navBar, black statusBar text)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

open/present vc2 and statusBar text will change its color

```
- (void)openVC2 {
    UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];
    [nvc.navigationBar setNavBarColor:COLOR_gray_light ShadowColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self presentViewController:nvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

info: setNavBarColor:ShadowColor: is a custom method within my category

Don´t forget to set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `YES` on your info.plist.